# Ubuntu stucks after boot with displaying '/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, xx/xx files, xx/xx blocks'

Tags: boot, gnome, 20.04

I can't get to login screen after booting ubuntu. Instead, after the loading screen this message shows up on black screen and nothing happens.

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, xx/xx files, xx/xx blocks
```

I tried to remove all nvidia packages using apt-get purge nvidia* and rebooted. Tried 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' in GRUB and boot to recovery mode, then tried the following options:

- clean
- dpkg
- fsck

All executed without error but fsck displayed following:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Before this has hapenned, I changed my critical battery setting to 'hibernate'. After that to test if it is working I emptied my battery, then I plugged and opened the pc, login screen showed up. But I couldn't type my password and it was repeatedly saying invalid password, as if the enter key is stucked. So I shutted down by pressing power button and after rebooting this started to happen.

So what exactly is the problem here?
Is it about Nvidia, Gnome, the hard disk or something else?